# Python notebook use return value from running a script

Tags: python

I am using a notebook (in Google Colab) in python 3 and really need to execute some python2 code with some data that is generated in my notebook !

So what I did was

1. Generate the data in my cells AND save it to a file (`data.txt`)
2. Write a python 2 script (`myScript.py`) with a `main()` function that parses the file from `sys.argv[1]` into data and than calls my python2 functions and do all the stuff then it ends with `return results` (which is a dictionary)
3. In my notebook I run

```sh
!python2 myScript.py ./data.txt
```

*(They are of course all in the same directory)*

The command runs with no errors but no output ! How do I catch the `results` that are returned in a variable that I could use later ?

---

**Not important but could be helpful :**

*Is there a better way to actually achieve what I am willing to achieve ?*

Comment: On possibility would be to make your python script write to stdout and read it back as a string:
`myvar = !python2 myScript.py ./data.txt`

myScript.py should write to stdout using print or similar.

`
def main():
    print('Hello World')
`

If you have a dictionary, you could either use eval() or print it csv like and parse back to a dict

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I didn't know we could do `myvar = !python2 myScript.py ./data.txt`, I used that insight to dump my dictionary as JSON then loading it from my notebook. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Manuel's comment on the question, I figured out this solution and it worked :

1. In `myScript.py`, I changed `return results` by `sys.stdout.write(json.dumps(results))`
2. In my notebook, I changed the cell that executes the script to this:

```py
results = !python2 test_langdetect.py ./tmp_comments.txt
myVar = json.loads(results[0])
```

*Of course you need to `import json`*